# 'nvm' is not recognized - but it's installed

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm trying to downgrade my node version to a specific version, so I installed nvm to try and help. It says in cmd that it's installed. But when I try and run any 'nvm' command, I get the error:

```
'nvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

[image]

Here's what I'm doing. You can see at the top, 'nvm' is not recognized error.

So I try and reinstall nvm, which it says it's already installed.

However no 'nvm' commands are working. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to navigate somewhere specific to use 'nvm' commands or something? I have closed and reopened my terminal many times, and this error still occurs.

Comment: Did you try closing and re-opening the terminal after you installed, like the message says?

Comment: Notice the commands listed at the bottom. You need to give those commands, or they need to be in your bash profile and you need to restart your terminal so that they take effect.

Comment: also you're using windows, you should use https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows instead, it notes it in the `readme.md` in nvm, that nvm-sh doesn't work on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to install Linux version of nvm to Windows PC.
You have several options here, depending on your needs:

- install and use nvm from [WSL environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)
- consider using [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Comment: This is all just so I can install a specific version of node. Can I just bypass all of this nvm nonsense and directly download an older version of node somewhere??? I know this is bad practice/nvm is easier/a thousand other reasons, but I literally just want node v12, then all my issues are solved. Do you know where/how would I get that?

Comment: @kdeez There is nothing wrong with just installing node.js. The nvm tool just makes it a little bit easier. Please look for proper version here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I'm sorry I'm still confused, this is my first time working with node. I go to the link you mentioned, I go to Node.js 12.x.... and then I'm just looking at that "Index of /dist/latest-v12.x/" page.... what exactly am I supposed to DO here to get it installed?

Comment: Check one .msi packages for windows installation. Select -x64 or -x86 depending on desired CPU architecture 64 or 32 bits. If you aren't going to use native modules with node, you can safely start with either option.